# System.InsufficientMemoryException: Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 536870912 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wshttpbinding

Below mentioned in Web.Config on Server Side.

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="00:50:00" openTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:50:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <reliableSession enabled="true" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="false" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Also at client side I mention below settings.

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
//binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10485760;
//binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760;
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
//binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
//binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000;2147483647
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
//binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
//binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 20000000;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
//binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);

//EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("user@domain");
ChannelFactory<IDBSyncContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IDBSyncContract>(binding, new EndpointAddress(endPointURL));
dbProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
this.dbProxy = dbProxy as IDBSyncContract;
```

I am getting above mentioned error.

Is there any concerns regarding wsHttpBindings.

Comment: The likely problem is that your WCF config sets many setting to maximum integer, 2 GB. Do you have a reason for making these settings?

Comment: To accomodate maximum data.Is there way to accomodate more Size .By increasing the size taht would suffice the above issue to be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the service is consuming all available memory on the host machine. I'd recommend that you remove **all** your config changes and return the config to the WCF default values. These default values were chosen by Microsoft for best performance in the average WCF service and you should only change them when you have a demonstrated need to do so.

The only exceptions I would recommend to the default values are the `maxReceivedMessageSize` and the `maxBufferSize` values. I'd start those at 262,144 bytes. If you get specific exceptions with any of these settings then changes only the affected setting.

If you're still having problems after upping a setting to max integer then consider changing your service design to get a successful call within the normal config setting. Staying as close as possible to the WCF default values will give your service the best overall performance.